# MODWT exceeds sample size (R)

Tags: r, wavelet-transform

I get the following message when I try to estimate rolling window wavelet correlation using package RolWinWavCor. I am trying to calculate the rolling window wavelet correlation for two stock indices.

wind= estim_RWWC(inputdata, Wname="la8", J=9, W=249, Align="center", Scale=TRUE)
Error in modwt(inputdata[i:w, 1], Wname, n.levels = J) :
wavelet transform exceeds sample size in modwt

Any help?

Whenever I run the following command this message comes on the screen
wavelet transform exceeds sample size in modwt

wind = estim_RWWC(inputdata, Wname="la8", J=9, W=249, Align="center", Scale=TRUE)
Error in modwt(inputdata[i:w, 1], Wname, n.levels = J) :
**wavelet transform exceeds sample size in modwt**

help me in removing this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.